# Conditional Variance formula $\mathbb{V}[\mu_t - \mu_{t|t-1} | F_{t-1}]$

Tags: conditional-expectation, finance, time-series

I am working on linear state space models of the form
$$\mu_{t+1} = \mu_t + e_t, \ \ \ \ e_t \sim N(0, \sigma_e^2)$$
$$y_{t} = \mu_t + \eta_t, \ \ \ \ \eta_t \sim N(0, \sigma_{\eta}^2)$$

where $\mu_t$ is a pure random walk

In the formula in the title, restated below for clarity, the term $\mu_{t|t-1}$ is the conditional mean of some state $\mu$ at time $t$ conditioned on all observations up until time $t-1$. So it can be written $\mathbb{E}[\mu_t | F_{t - 1}]$ where $F_{t-1}$ is the set of observations $\{y_1, .., y_{t-1}\}$

I am trying to work out here, if the conditional mean, $\mu_{t|t-1}$, is in fact a constant?

$$\mathbb{V}[\mu_t - \mu_{t|t-1} | F_{t-1}]$$

The text I am reading, *Financial Time Series Analysis by Tsay*, states that the above formula for the variance is actually $$\mathbb{V}[\mu_t | F_{t-1}]$$

Could someone confirm for me please?

Btw this crops up on page 561 in Eq 2.11 of Financial Time Series Analysis by Tsay

Comment: You mean the question is if the conditional variance is a constant?

Comment: No, the second term in the conditional variance I have presented

Comment: What’s the notation fancy V?

Comment: That is the Variance (sorry I thought this was standard). Essentially I am asking what the variance of $(\mu_t - \mu_{t-1}) | F_{t-1}$ is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a martingale, then the expectation of the next value in the sequence is equal to the present value. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory))

Since the previous value is part of the filtration, if the sequence of RVs is a martingale, then $\mathbb{E} [X_{t+1}|X_t] = X_t$ and $\mathbb{E} [X_{t+1}|X_t,F] = x_t$, where $x_t$ is the value $X_t$ took.

---

We use the fact that

1. $y_{t|t-1} = \mathbb{E}[y_t|F] = \mathbb{E}[\mu_t+\eta_t|F) = \mathbb{E}[\mu_t|F] = \mu_{t|t-1}$
2. $\mu_{t|t-1}=y_{t|t-1}=\mathbb{E}[y_t|y_{t-1},F] = y_{t-1}$ which is constant given it's part of the history F.
3. $Var [\mu_t - \mu_{t|t-1} | F_{t-1}]=Var [\mu_t - y_{t-1} | F_{t-1}]=Var [\mu_t | F_{t-1}]$

Comment: I am not sure it is a Martingale (and I am not exactly sure what this is as I have not covered it yet). The author just states that it is a Linear state space model and that $\mu_t$ is a pure random walk

Comment: I've added some details. Please see if it makes sense now?

Comment: I completely understand this and agree with you. I am going to make some edits to my question, but what I want to know is how to deal with $Var[\mu_t - \mu_{t-1} | F_t]$ which I will try to expand using the definition $Var(x) = E(x^2) - E(x)^2$

Comment: $\mu_{t-1}$ is part of the filtration F. Thus it's a known quantity, which is like a constant and does not contribute to the variance. Does it become easier to see if we write $Var[\mu_t - \mu_{t-1} | F_t]=Var[\mu_t - k | F_t] $? Then $Var[\mu_t - \mu_{t-1} | F_t]  = Var[\mu_t  | F_t]$

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that this may not hold due to the law of iterated expectation, namely $E[E[X|Y] = E[X]$? Since $\mu_{t|t-1} = E[\mu_t | F_{t-1}]$ I thought that $E[\mu_{t|t-1}] = E[E[\mu_t | F_{t-1}]] = E[\mu_t]$. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Consider this clearer notation of the law of iterated expectation. $E_Y[E_{X|Y}[X=x|Y=y] = E[X]$. In this case the first expectation is over all $Y$, which in our case would be the expectation over all possible filtrations (as Y is F in the equation you wrote). But a single filtration F (or history) is given to us, and we may not iterate over all possible histories. Please do correct me in case this understanding is wrong

Comment: Why can we not iterate over them? $F_t = \{y_1, ..., y_t\}$ so why can we not iterate over all previous observations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122775/discussion-between-rahul-madhavan-and-investingscientist).